# How to set content disposition in Sonata/Symfony 3.3?

Tags: php, symfony, http, sonata

I have a Sonata app running atop Symfony 3.3. Currently, it includes a block service that passes a PDF file from the service to a template via the following code:

```
public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null)
{
    $block = $blockContext->getBlock();
    $this->load($block);
    $settings = $block->getSettings();
    $media = $block->getSetting('media');

    $blockContext->setSetting('template', 'AppBundle:Block:block_pdf.html.twig');
    return $this->renderResponse($blockContext->getTemplate(), array(
        'block' => $block,
        'settings' => $settings,
        'media' => $media,
    ), $response);
}
```

... and my Twig code looks like this:

```
<figure class="col-md-12">
    <a href="{% path media, 'reference' %}">View as PDF</a>
</figure>
```

That works OK, but I find that when I link to the media in my Twig template, the PDF opens in the browser.

**I would like to set the disposition of the file so that it downloads instead of opening in the browser. How do I do that?**

What I have tried so far: Digging around in Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Meida and its parent class did not seem to yield any methods that do this. Perhaps I was looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

TIL there's a plain old HTML way to do this.

```
<a href="{% path media, 'reference' %}" target="_blank" download>View as PDF</a>
```

https://caniuse.com/#feat=download